# Javascript multiplayer game collisions shaking

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-physics, collision

I have a problem when there is a collision between 2 players (we always see the oppenent shaking).

Here is a video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xu8DTKngVjg

Here is the client code :

```
class Player {
    static list = new Map();
    constructor(properties) {
        Player.list.set(properties.id, this);
        this.id = properties.id;
        this.x = properties.x * zoom;
        this.y = properties.y * zoom;
    }

    update() {
        this.sX = this.x - camera.x + document.documentElement.clientWidth / 2;
        this.sY = this.y - camera.y + document.documentElement.clientHeight / 2;

        //Draw the player
    }
}



function animate() {
    Player.list.forEach(player => {
        player.animate();
    });

    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}


animate();


socket.on("positions", function (data) {
    if (Player.list.has(data.id)) {
        if (data.id === clientID && startedGameplay === true) {
            camera.x = data.x * zoom;
            camera.y = data.y * zoom;
        }

        Player.list.get(data.id).x = data.x * zoom;
        Player.list.get(data.id).y = data.y * zoom;
    }
});
```

And here is the server code :

```
class Player {
        static list = new Map();
        constructor(properties) {
            Player.list.set(properties.id, this);
            this.id = properties.id;
            this.x = properties.x;
            this.y = properties.y;
        }
    
        update() {
            //Player moves
            move(this);
    
    
            //Chek for collisions
            Player.list.forEach(player => {
                if (player.id != this.id) {
                    const distance = Math.hypot(this.y - player.y, this.x - player.x) || 1;
                    collisions(distance, this, player);
                }
            });
    
            io.emit("positions", this.getPosition());
        }

        getPosition() {
           return {
             id: this.id,
             x: this.x,
             y: this.y,
           }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    //Collisions function
    function collisions(distance, player, obj) {
        if (distance <= player.hitboxRadius + obj.hitboxRadius) {
            const dX = (player.hitboxRadius + obj.hitboxRadius) * (obj.x - player.x) / distance;
            const dY = (player.hitboxRadius + obj.hitboxRadius) * (obj.y - player.y) / distance;
        
            obj.x = player.x + dX;
            obj.y = player.y + dY;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    //Function to make the player move
    function move(player) {
        if (player.movingUp === true) {
            player.vy -= player.moveSpeed;
        }
            
        else if (player.movingDown === true) {
            player.vy += player.moveSpeed;
        }
        
        if (player.movingRight === true) {
            player.vx += player.moveSpeed;
        }
            
        else if (player.movingLeft === true) {
            player.vx -= player.moveSpeed;
        }
    
        player.x += player.vx;
        player.y += player.vy;
    
        player.vx *= 0.9;
        player.vy *= 0.9;
    }
    
    
    
    //Loop every 10ms to update players
    setInterval(() => {
        Player.list.forEach(player => {
            player.update();
        });
    }, 10);
```

I dont think the problem come from the collisions detection/response, because if I update sX and sY every time I recieve the position pack and not on the players update function, the collisions work fine without shaking. I actually need to update sX and sY on players update functions.

Can anyone help me ?

(sX and sY are the positions of the players in relation to the position of the client player who is placed in the center of the screen).

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you may want to put the `move` function on the server inside the `Player` class. Additionally, your on positions callback function could be cleaned up to say `const player = Player.list.get(data.id)`, then check against undefined. Alternatively, you could emit `positions-${this.id}` from the server, then not need to iterate through the player list and just subscribe to the specific client ID positions event.

Comment: Looking at the video it appears to me that the "shaking" is coming from the players giving each other a continual series of little "micro-bumbs".  So the centering makes the player appear to be smooth, but makes the opponent appear to be jerky/shaking because it is not being moved continuously by the player, but rather is a series of bumbs.  String those together and that appears jerky.  So, I don't think that there's anything wrong with your animation, I think that it is accurately portraying what the physics is doing, just the centering makes everything else appear a bit shakier than it is.

Comment: So there is no solution ? I dont think, bcs i know others games like that, and they dont have this issue

Comment: I assume that their physical step interval is much smaller than their display update interval, which should smooth it out.

Answer (score 0):

I move collision function into the player class. it works for me.